# is my radius of convergence correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, power-series

Consider the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left (1+{1 \over 2}+....+{1 \over n} \right )x^n$ .

I applied the ratio test and I ended up getting it to simplify to:

$$x \lim_{n \to \infty} {n \over n+1}$$ from which I concluded that x(1) 
=x
=x<1 therefore the radius of convergence is 1

Comment: What do you mean by $x(1)$?

Comment: the limit as n goes to infinity of n/(n+1) i got it to equal 1 and I have factored out a x before so i would get x(times the limit) since the limit was 1 i got x(1)

Comment: What is the series? (1/n)x^n?

Comment: I assume so but my prof wrote it like how it is above for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.  Note that the difference in adjacent coefficients is just $\frac 1 {n+1}$, which goes to $0$ as $n\to \infty$,  so your ratio of coefficients is pretty clearly going to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the function may be written as $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i}\right)x^n$.  Interchanging the order of summation yields

$$\begin{align}
f(x) & = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}\right) x^n \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i} \sum_{n=i}^{\infty} x^n \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i} \frac{x^i}{1-x}
\end{align}$$

where we have summed the geometric series to arrive at this last expression - assuming $|x|<1$.  The series is the Taylors series for the natural logarithm at $1-x$.  Thus, we have for $|x|<1$

$$f(x) = \frac{-\log (1-x)}{1-x}$$

The series diverges for $|x|\ge1$.

---

A second way to analyze the problem is to recognize that the partial sums 
$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i}\right) = \log (n) + \gamma +O(n^{-1})$.  Thus, the ratio

$$\frac{\log (n+1) + \gamma +O(n^{-1})}{\log (n) + \gamma +O(n^{-1})} \to 1$$

as $n \to \infty$.  Thus, the series converges for $|x|<1$ and diverges elsewhere.  This agrees with the previous conclusion!

Comment: Hi @Mark Viola. This is a very late question haha, but since I'm working on this problem myself. Could you maybe explain the procedure where you interchanged the summations, and changed the indices. I'd be glad if you could explain why this step works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

More precisely,
$1+{1 \over 2}+....+{1 \over n}
\sim \ln n
$,
so, since
$\frac{\ln n}{\ln(n+1)}
\to 1$,
the radius of convergence is $1$.

Generalizing Alan's solution,
if
$A(x)
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\sum_{i=1}^n a_i
$
where
$a_i > 0$
and
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{a_n}{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}
= 0$,
the radius of convergence
of $A(x)$
is $1$.

Comment: Yes!  That is one of the ways that I analyzed this problem.  Another way to analyze this problem is to find a closed-form expression for the series ... it is $\frac{-\log (1-x)}{(1-x)}$ for $|x| <1$.